# How to build dynamic query by expression in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression-trees

First, I have a variable like below:

```
List<string> values;
```

Now I need build query condition like below:

```
Expression<Func<docinstance, bool>> filter = d=>d.values.any(o=>o.value==values[0]||o.value==value[1]||.....)
```

Because I don't know how many items in variable values, so how can I build the query condition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Any` again inside

```
d => d.values.Any(o => values.Any(x => x == o.value))
```

Comment: This generates a double EXIST and `2(n-1)` UNIONs of single row tables. `Contains` is *much* better (1 IN clause).

Comment: @GertArnold - In what ways is it _better_? Is execution faster? Is the Query Execution Plan different?

Comment: `Contains` has scalability problems, but `Any` is not scalable at all. When `values` has relatively many elements (~50) the query will throw an exception "nested too deeply".

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Contains`:

```
d => d.values.Any(o => values.Contains(o.value))
```

See [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The [DbContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx) class of EF has a method [Set<TEntity>()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696521(v=vs.113).aspx) which return type is [DbSet<TEntity>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460(v=vs.113).aspx) which implements [Queryable interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which has all the query methods as extension methods.

At the end your query expression in translated into SQL and then executed. Which gives you the desired capability so that you can combine query methods and construct dynamic expressions.